# OpenJPA with Spring: how to integrate persistence.xml into applicationContext.xml?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

Current application running on SpringMVC3+OpenJPA2.2

What we trying to achieve, is that can make `schema` name in persistence.xml can be defined by `external properties file`. Seems not quite doable without java code change. But that seems requires quite a few code change.

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834954/loading-properties-in-spring-context-xml-and-persistence-xml) post I find there is a way to put everything from persistence.xml into applicationContext.xml in hibernate. Now the question becomes (how) can we make the same happen in OpenJPA?

Comment: could you edit the question and post your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @fmodos Thank you but we have very very long content under applicationContext.xml, as quite a few beans are defined under current application.

Comment: Ok @Dreame, it seems that it is not possible on OpenJPA check [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0708_vines/0708_vines.html) link "If no persistence.xml is found with a matching name, then a javax.persistence.PersistenceException is raised."

Comment: @fmodos That's very sad. But thanks for the intel. So only two options available then? 1. persistence defined in Java 2. Swtich to Hibernate. Both are a pain in the mess...Any other options?

Comment: It's open source, you could hack something in yourself.... and then contribute it back?