# How to define - environment specifc mongo db configuration in play framework with JpaApi?

Tags: mongodb, jpa, playframework, sbt, hibernate-ogm

I am working on a project where I am using play framework along with mongo db. As of now I have hardcoded the value for local db connection in persistence.xml file and given the **jpa.default** value as persistenceUnitName and I am using the play's JpaApi for the db operations (which inherently uses the entity manager).

I am not able to identify how to define environment (prod, dev, stage) specific db properties like host, url etc. in application.conf or any other file.

application.conf entry - **jpa.default=my-local-jpa**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="my-local-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"
                  value="org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host"
                  value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.port" value="27017"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="my_db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.safe" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if you can refer in the configuration file to environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

There would be different solutions. It depends on your environment.

If you are using WildFly / JEE container, you can configure a WildFly NoSQL subsystem, providing there the references to the remote datastore. It would be the equivalent of a SQL datasource, but for a NoSQL datastore. See [Using WildFly NoSQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#integration-with-wildfly-nosql)

If you are using a web container, there would be different strategies. 
You can create different war(s), one for each environment, for instance using maven profiles.
Alternatively, you can configure your Spring context in order to use an external property file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834954/loading-properties-in-spring-context-xml-and-persistence-xml).

If you deploy it in a PASS, such as OpenShift, you can mount the persistence.xml file as a config map. See [Config Map - OpenShift doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html)